# "QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread" in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I got the problem about timers which is

> QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread

Below is the log data from my terminal.

```
$ ./boost_tutorials 
init done
All done. Exit safely!
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
```

Here is my C++ code with thread from boost. I build it via CMakeLists.

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

class Robot {
public:
  Robot() {
    cap.open(-1);
    SYSTEM_QUIT = false;
    if (!cap.isOpened()) {
      cout << "Error opening the video" << endl;
      SYSTEM_QUIT = true;
    }
  }

  ~Robot() {
    destroyAllWindows();
    cout << "All done. Exit safely!" << endl;
  }

  void run() {
    boost::thread* t1 = new boost::thread(boost::bind(&Robot::imageProcCallback, this));
    boost::thread* t2 = new boost::thread(boost::bind(&Robot::simpleCallback, this));
    t1->join();
    t2->join();
  }

  void imageProcCallback() {
    Mat frame;
    int cc = 0;
    while(!SYSTEM_QUIT) {
      cap >> frame;
      if (!msgs.empty()) {
        Point pt(rand()%frame.cols, rand()%frame.rows);
        putText(frame, msgs.back(), pt, cv::FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 2, Scalar(0, 255, 0));
     }

     imshow(filename, frame);
     if (waitKey(5) == 27)
       SYSTEM_QUIT = true;
     }
     frame.release();
  }

  void simpleCallback() {
    while(!SYSTEM_QUIT) {
      int count = rand() % 100;
      std::string str = std::to_string(count);
      msgs.push_back(str);
    }
  }

private:
  string filename;
  VideoCapture cap;
  bool SYSTEM_QUIT;
  std::vector<std::string> msgs;
};

void main() {
  Robot robot;
  robot.run();
}
```

Comment: None of this seems thread-safe. You need to hide `SYSTEM_QUIT` in a `std::atomic<bool>` and have a `mutex` for `msgs` at the very least.

Comment: You're also leaking `boost::thread*`s. I see no need for the dynamic allocations.

Comment: Googling this in the context of OpenCV, it seems that people are resolving it by rebuilding OpenCV without Qt. I don't know whether that's because OpenCV has a bug in this regard, or because those people gave up before finding the _true_ cause of the problem. But fixing your MT issues would certainly be a good start.

Comment: @Tas I tried with the 'std::atomic<bool>' but the timer problem remains the same.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I also think that it is about the OpenCV bug.